# Is there a way to to make the iPhone 8 version look the same as the iPod touch one?

Tags: iphone, xcode, autolayout

I originally made an app that works on iPhones but I want it to work on a thinner iPod touch (I am using autolayout). I have an issue of the screen not completely being shown in the iPod touch version. It looks like this.

[image: iPhone 8 version]

[image: iPod Touch version]

I have looked into size classes but the size classes for both models is the same. I'm wondering if there is a framework that can solve my issue or if there is an autolayout trick.

Comment: Are you doing auto layout with code or with storyboard ? It seems like your are using fixed sizes . Did you set constraints for leading,trailing,top,bottom ? But without more context it is not possible to help.

Comment: I'm doing autolayout with storyboard and I set constraints too but I made my white square a fixed size.